# Do button's touch size change with a CGAffineTransformScale?

Tags: uiview, uibutton, cgaffinetransformscale

My goal was to make a View of buttons and have it grow with screen size so it works on all devices, filling 90% of the width of the screen. **I am not using constraints** as it is an older program, and turning on constraints would be too big a job right now. I was hoping to "cheat" my way around this. So, I tried this:

I have a smaller View created inside a full screen View (created in interface builder) that is basically a standard "view" item. Inside that smaller View are a bunch of UIButtons that make my "keyboard."

I would like to scale the smaller view (which visually scales the buttons too), and still have the buttons respond properly as they change size. So I have done this:

Setup: 
View (buttonView) with UIButtons inside that view. The view and the buttons are attached (in Interface Builder) to IBOutlets and IBActions as necessary. The following code scales the view to match the screen:

```
_keyboardCard.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;   // reset to normal
CGFloat keyboardWidth   =  _keyboardCard.bounds.size.width;
// screenWidth is set earlier and has width bounds value for full screen
CGFloat widthScale = (screenWidth/keyboardWidth)*0.9;   // 90% of full screen width
_keyboardCard.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, widthScale, widthScale);
```

This actually works **visually** just fine, and the "keyboardCard" grows in size, as do the buttons inside (visually), just like I expected. It looks good as I change from device to device.

But there are times when some of the buttons stop responding. SOME continue to work just fine, especially near the center, while others just stop. The touch failures start on ALL the edges, and work their way inward as the size grows. It is almost as if there is a "mask" stopping the buttons from working on the edges.

So the question is: Is this a legitimate ways to do this? It does not seem to be documented anywhere. And if not, what does one suggest as a way to make a view with buttons scale up and down and still have the buttons work as expected?

Or perhaps I am just better off making a small, medium, and large View of the "keyboard", and just pick the closest one based on screen size?

Suggestions and comments please. Thank you.

Comment: One more comment: For the buttons that do work, their touch points are exactly the size of the scaled button. So the buttons that can be touched, do work as expected.

Comment: Well, turns out, after much playing, that I CAN do this. the problem was with the parent view, which was not being scaled. The sub-views scaled larger than the parent view. The visuals seem to not care, but the parent view being smaller, clipped the touches. SIGH!.

So I changed this to scale the parent view instead, and EVERYTHING works. It seems you can scale a view, and the touch areas for the buttons scale with them.